# Looking for an iOS Layout Library

Tags: ios, layout

Does anyone know of a layout library that performs acceptably on iOS? I'm looking for a tool that can layout network devices in different patterns such as circular, tree, organic, orthogonal, and hierarchical layouts. I'm looking for something very similar to yFiles for Java/Android: http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_practicalinfo_gallery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omni Graffle is a great one. Made by the guys over at `omni group` I think its about $19.99 but its totally worth it! It works on iPad and mac!

Comment: Thank you. They have an open source library on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visio is good for architecture design. Another is OmniGraffle like @CodeBandits said.